# Maven and Android SDK Deployer issue with Mediarouter

Tags: android, maven-3, maven-plugin, android-maven-plugin

I am simply trying to setup maven on my machine to build Android projects.

I have maven 3.1.1. 
And have installed all platforms from the Android SDK Manager.

When I do:
   `mvn clean install`

on `Maven-Android-SDK-Deployer`,

Everything seems to work until it encounters **Compatibility v7 Mediarouter Library** 
and then the build fails. See the logs below:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Android Compatibility Extra V7 Mediarouter Library 2.4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:apklib:19.0.0 i
s missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:jar:19.0.0 is m
issing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Maven Android SDK Deployer ........................ SUCCESS [0.345s]
[INFO] Android Platforms ................................. SUCCESS [0.020s]
[INFO] Android Platform 1.5 API 3 ........................ SUCCESS [0.131s]
[INFO] Android Platform 1.6 API 4 ........................ SUCCESS [0.065s]
[INFO] Android Platform 2.1 API 7 ........................ SUCCESS [0.071s]
[INFO] Android Platform 2.2 API 8 ........................ SUCCESS [0.052s]
[INFO] Android Platform 2.3.3 API 10 ..................... SUCCESS [0.059s]
[INFO] Android Platform 3.0 API 11 ....................... SUCCESS [0.054s]
[INFO] Android Platform 3.1 API 12 ....................... SUCCESS [0.058s]
[INFO] Android Platform 3.2 API 13 ....................... SUCCESS [0.052s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.0 API 14 ....................... SUCCESS [0.053s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.0.3 API 15 ..................... SUCCESS [0.059s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.1 API 16 ....................... SUCCESS [0.042s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.2 API 17 ....................... SUCCESS [6.604s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.3 API 18 ....................... SUCCESS [6.278s]
[INFO] Android Platform 4.4 API 19 ....................... SUCCESS [6.683s]
[INFO] Android Add-Ons ................................... SUCCESS [0.015s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 1.5 API 3 (Maps) ... SUCCESS [0.030s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 1.6 API 4 (Maps) ... SUCCESS [0.025s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 2.1 API 7 (Maps) ... SUCCESS [0.023s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 2.2 API 8 (Maps) ... SUCCESS [0.029s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 2.3.3 API 10 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.031s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 3.0 API 11 (Maps) .. SUCCESS [0.023s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 3.1 API 12 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.029s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 3.2 API 13 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.036s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.0 API 14 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.044s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.0.3 API 15 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.035s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.1 API 16 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.045s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.2 API 17 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.050s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.3 API 18 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.041s]
[INFO] Android Add-On Google Platform 4.4 API 19 (Maps and USB)  SUCCESS [0.029s]
[INFO] Google Glass Development Kit (GDK) API 15 ......... SUCCESS [0.024s]
[INFO] Android Extras .................................... SUCCESS [0.017s]
[INFO] Android Compatibility Extra V4 .................... SUCCESS [0.142s]
[INFO] Android Compatibility Extra V7 Gridlayout Library . SUCCESS [2.592s]
[INFO] Android Compatibility Extra V7 AppCompat Library .. SUCCESS [1.918s]
[INFO] Android Compatibility Extra V7 Mediarouter Library  FAILURE [0.028s]
[INFO] Android Compatibility Extra V13 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Analytics Extra .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google AdMob Ads Extra .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Cloud Messaging Library Extra Parent  SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Cloud Messaging Client Library Extra  SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Cloud Messaging Server Library Extra  SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Play Services Extra ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Play Licensing Extra ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Extras - Apk Expansion .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Play APK Expansion Extra - ZIP ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Google Play APK Expansion Extra - Downloader  SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Tools ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android Annotations ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Repositories ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Google M2Repository ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Android M2Repository .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.470s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 13 21:33:06 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/312M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project compatibility-v7-mediarouter: 
    Could not resolve dependencies for projectcom.simpligility.android.sdk-deployer:compatibility-v7-mediarouter:apklib:2.4.0: 
    The following artifacts could not be resolved:android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:apklib:19.0.0, android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:jar:19.0.0: 
    Failure to find android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:apklib:19.0.0 
    in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the localrepository, 
    resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange bug:

Fixed it finally by only uninstalling the support-libraries from Android SDK Manager,
and then re-installing them both afterwards.

```
Android SDK Manager > Extras > Android Support Repository
Android SDK Manager > Extras > Android Support Library
```

Comment: This a consequence of Google changing the components of the SDK and their property files around all the time. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You have to accept it yourself since you asked the question. You probably have to wait a while since you are a noob on stackoverflow

Comment: Just seem a little arrogant about your stackoverflow ratings though :)
but cheers

Comment: It is the right answer but nobody else than the person who asked the question can accept the answer and as a beginner with a low number of points you have to wait longer. Thats all. Thats how stackoverflow works .. there is not arrogance on my side. There are lots of people with lots more points and I dont really work on that. Just trying to help people using my software (e.g. here the Maven Android SDK Deployer)