# Android support library not deploying on maven repository

Tags: android, maven

Actually i am deploying android support -v4 via  android sdk deployer

so i followed this link :-https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Finally getting following error. on command prompt.

[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :compatibility-v7-mediarouter

Followed link :-[Maven and Android SDK Deployer issue with Mediarouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575712/maven-and-android-sdk-deployer-issue-with-mediarouter)

No solutions

Please help me .
Thanks

Comment: you should install the jar into your local repository.

Comment: I am installing in local repository through android sdk deployer.While installing i am getting this error.

Comment: I resolved this issue. My maven android sdk deployer path was too long.